# errors with "segmentation fault occurred "

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have some values written in file 4 and I need them to call again for new calculations but I have some problem in read line " read (4,*) NNrow(I),Niz(I),NNbin(I),Nfi(I),NfiStdDev(I),NfiAvr(I),NMagbin(I),Nzup(I) " 
when I want to run the code I'm receiving the error "segmentation fault occurred" how I can use this file again?

```
                                 do j=1,nmax
                                    if (zb(iz,im,j).ne.0) then
              call Romberg (dix,dDistCa,zb(iz,im,j),zup(iz))                    !COMOVING DISTANCE
              Vmax=dix*S                                    !COMOVINF VOLUME
              fi=fi+1/Vmax                                    !LUMINOSITY FUNCTION
 write(2,'(i5,2x,f9.4,2x,f8.5,2x,3f14.10)')j,magbin,zbin,S,Vmax,dix
            endif

        enddo

            if (Nbin.ge.n_thresh) then
    Nrow=Nrow+1
write(4,'(3i7,2x,f25.8,2x,2f20.8,2x,f9.4,2x,f8.5)')Nrow,iz,Nbin,fi,fiStdDev,fiAvr,magbin,zup(iz)
            endif
              enddo loopmag

rewind(4)
close(4)


write(*,*)Nrow 
 open(4,file='luminosity_func_I.asc')

 allocate (fiStdDev2(Nrow),stat=ok)
 allocate (fi_expected(Nrow),stat=ok)
 allocate (DFI(Nrow),stat=ok)
 allocate (CHISQ(Nrow),stat=ok)
 ! Ln10=2.3025
 A=0.4*2.3025
            do I=1,Nrow        ! NDATA=NMAX
            write(*,*)I
                read (4,*) NNrow(I),Niz(I),NNbin(I),Nfi(I),NfiStdDev(I),NfiAvr(I),NMagbin(I),Nzup(I)

                  fiStdDev2(I)=1/NfiStdDev(I)*NfiStdDev(I)
            write(*,*)fiStdDev2(I)
                  fi_expected(I)=A*fi_star*10**(0.4*(alpha+1)*(M_star-NMagbin(I)))*exp(-10**(0.4*(M_star-NMagbin(I))))
                  DFI(I)=fi_expected(I)-NFI(I)
                  CHISQ(I)=DFI(I)*DFI(I)*fiStdDev2(I)
            END DO
```

Comment: Good grief, how can you possibly figure out what such badly formatted code is doing, and why do you expect us to bother ?  While you're formatting it for legibility and comprehensibility delete the commented-out lines and the excessive blank lines too.

Comment: I'm sorry if you think I want to bother you, I 'm sure that I 'm doing very small and stupid mistake but I can't find it that's why I asked you and I tried to send you the main part which is related to this error as it's very long code and I think I should have some limitations for sending of all of it.any way thanks for your answer

Comment: Segmentation faults generally only occur in Fortran if you are trying to access an element of an array that does not exist (i.e., index 23 when the defined maximum length is 22). It is likely that `Nrow` is probably larger than the maximum length of your variables in that line.

Comment: Also, I agree with what @HighPerformanceMark is saying. Your code is indented in such a strange manner that it is likely people here who *can* help you *won't* want to because it is a headache to try reading that. If you stick with 3 or 4 spaces (not tabs) within each `DO` loop and `IF` statement, your code instantly becomes readable to all.

Comment: @user2717742: If you want the question answered, have a modicum of courtesy to the people who help you and clean up the formatting. Let us help you. So far, it's an instant turn-off. It doesn't matter what the scope or magnitude of your "stupid mistake" is. You want help, you need to put some effort. Sane formatting is a minimum of effort everyone who asks on SO should show.

Comment: The code you provided is incomplete... Could you provide the beginning of the loop `loopmag` and the declarations of `zb`, `zup`, `NNrow`, `Niz`, `NNbin`, `Nfi`, `NfiStdDev`, `NfiAvr`, `NMagbin`, `Nzup`?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, there could be two things going wrong in that `read` statement:

1. You are trying to store the information outside the arrays, i.e. `i > size(<one of the arrays>)`. You can check for this with `-fbounds-check` for `gfortran` and `-check bounds` for `ifort`.
2. There's something wrong while reading in from the file:

   - The unit is pretty low, you could access a reserved unit - try something like `1234`. See also this post: [segmentation error in linux for ansys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263154/segmentation-error-in-linux-for-ansys)
   - You read beyond the end of the file
   - There are not enough columns to read from the file

You could put `iostat=ierror` into your `read` statement to check whether an error occured while reading in. `ierror<0` would mean that you are trying to read beyond the end of the file, while `ierror>0` corresponds to an error while reading the file.