# how to solve "segmentation fault" error?

Tags: fortran90

I have some values written in file 4 which I need to read them again for new calculations but I'm receiving segmentation fault error while I'm running code which this problem occurres in read command "read (4,*) NNrow(I),Niz(I),NNbin(I),Nfi(I),NfiStdDev(I),NfiAvr(I),NMagbin(I),Nzup(I)"
how I can solve this problem?

```
        do j=1,nmax
            if (zb(iz,im,j).ne.0) then

              call Romberg (dix,dDistCa,zb(iz,im,j),zup(iz))                    !COMOVING DISTANCE
              Vmax=dix*S                                    !COMOVINF VOLUME
              fi=fi+1/Vmax                                    !LUMINOSITY FUNCTION
write(2,'(i5,2x,f9.4,2x,f8.5,2x,3f14.10)')j,magbin,zbin,S,Vmax,dix
            endif

        enddo

            if (Nbin.ge.n_thresh) then
    Nrow=Nrow+1
write(4,'(3i7,2x,f25.8,2x,2f20.8,2x,f9.4,2x,f8.5)')Nrow,iz,Nbin,fi,fiStdDev,fiAvr,magbin,zup(iz)
            endif
              enddo loopmag

rewind(4)
close(4)


write(*,*)Nrow 
open(4,file='luminosity_func_I.asc')

allocate (fiStdDev2(Nrow),stat=ok)
allocate (fi_expected(Nrow),stat=ok)
allocate (DFI(Nrow),stat=ok)
allocate (CHISQ(Nrow),stat=ok)
! Ln10=2.3025
 A=0.4*2.3025
            do I=1,Nrow        ! NDATA=NMAX
            write(*,*)I
                read (4,*) NNrow(I),Niz(I),NNbin(I),Nfi(I),NfiStdDev(I),NfiAvr(I),NMagbin(I),Nzup(I)

                  fiStdDev2(I)=1/NfiStdDev(I)*NfiStdDev(I)
            write(*,*)fiStdDev2(I)
                  fi_expected(I)=A*fi_star*10**(0.4*(alpha+1)*(M_star-NMagbin(I)))*exp(-10**(0.4*(M_star-NMagbin(I))))
                  DFI(I)=fi_expected(I)-NFI(I)
                  CHISQ(I)=DFI(I)*DFI(I)*fiStdDev2(I)
            END DO
```

Comment: No, no, no. Do not post the same question again. [errors with "segmentation fault occurred "](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400039/errors-with-segmentation-fault-occurred)

Answer (score -1):

I am no fortran expert but from my C experience on Linux all I would say is keep debugging until you find the cause, may be one of the variable is not initialized properly and used just like that.

What is `I` in your code? have you initialized it??

Comment: yes to I need to read and use all those values as an array