# Where is the run time error of the 7th line (reading matrix from file)?

Tags: fortran, fortran77

Code:

```
program a
implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)
dimension a(3,3),b(3)

open(1,file='matrix.dat')
do i=1,3
    read(1,*) b(i)(a(i,j),j=1,3)
enddo
close(1)

stop
end
```

Error:

```
At line 7 of file ea.for (unit=1, file='matrix.dat')
Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

matrix a(3*3), b(3):

```
3
2.d0   -7.d0    4.d0    4.d0
1.d0    9.d0   -6.d0    4.d0
-3.d0    8.d0    5.d0    2.d0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `1` as unit number - try something like `1234`.! The lower unit numbers are reserved for "special units" like `STDOUT`, `STDERR`, `STDIN`.
See also this post: [segmentation error in linux for ansys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263154/segmentation-error-in-linux-for-ansys)

To check whether you are trying to read beyond the end of the file or the wrong number of columns you could put `iostat=ierror` into your `read` statement to check whether an error occured while reading in. `ierror<0` corresponds to "end of file", while `ierror>0` means that an error occured during `read`.

If what you have given for the matrix values corresponds to the file `matrix.dat`, then you are not reading in the first (integer) value `3`.

This is for illustration and should work:

```
program a_test
  implicit none
  real    :: a(3,3),b(3)
  integer :: dummy, ierror, i, j

  open(unit=1234,file='matrix.dat')
  read(1234,*) dummy
  do i=1,3
      read(1234,*,iostat=ierror) b(i),(a(i,j),j=1,3)
      if (ierror>0) then
        stop 'Error while reading from file. '
      elseif (ierror<0) then
        stop 'Reached end of file. '
      endif
  enddo
  close(1234)

  write(*,*) 'a='
  write(*,*) a(1,:)
  write(*,*) a(2,:)
  write(*,*) a(3,:)
  write(*,*) 'b=',b
end
```

Comment: Is it a mistake to write the number 3(=matrix(3x3)) in the beginning of the matrix.dat? thank you in advance.

Comment: That depends... If you don't know how big the matrix in the file actually is, it is a good idea to store the matrix size/shape (Actually, it would be required to do so to set the correct ranges). For Fortran 90+ you could also work with `allocatable` arrays that you would `allocate` after reading in the matrix size/shape. If your matrix size is fixed, you can hard-code the sizes and don't need to store it to file.

Answer (score 0):

Read-commands in Fortran move the active point in the file to the next line so that the next read-command can read the next line. My best guess is that the last call to "read" is looking for an endline character, trying to move on to the next line, but running into the end of the file instead. See if adding a hard return at the end of the input file fixes the problem. (I know some older editors complain if you don't have a blank line at the end of a file, and I think this is why.)

Comment: It looks more like the problem lies in reading the first line; he is telling the program that there will be 4 values there and the program finds 1.

Comment: Nah. The problem was End of File.
Alexander was right. Unit 1 in Fortran is reserved for keyboard-input.